# Query to get result based on dates in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Need to get result from query where start date and end date is in between the period and end date is nil

**Tried this query**

```
lines.where('((DATE(start_date) >= DATE(?) AND DATE(?) <= DATE(end_date)) or (DATE(start_date) >= DATE(?) AND DATE(end_date) is null))', start_date, end_date, start_date)
```

**Database**

```
Line 1 
start_date end_date
Oct 1, 2020 Oct 31, 2020
Line 2 
start_date end_date
01/01/2020   nil (MM/DD/YY)
Line 3 
start_date end_date
Oct 1, 2020 Jun 1, 2021
Line 4 
start_date end_date
Apr 1, 2021 Apr 30, 2021
```

Query where start_date and end_date is Oct 1, 2020 and Feb 1, 2021

result should be

```
Line 1 
start_date end_date
Oct 1, 2020 Oct 31, 2020
Line 2 
start_date end_date
01/01/2020   nil (MM/DD/YY)
Line 3 
start_date end_date
Oct 1, 2020 Jun 1, 2021
```

How can we do it?

Comment: You should not have to use `DATE()` unless you're doing something stupid like storing dates as integers or strings.  Usually in Postgres you would just use `BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` to test if a date is within a range. What types are your columns? Its also unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish as your requirements contradict themselves - "end date is in between the period and end date is nil" if its nil then the first condition will never be true. Can you provide an example of the data and a better example of the output (like a simple ASCII table)?

Answer (score 0):

```
lines.where('((DATE(start_date) >= DATE(?) AND DATE(end_date) <= DATE(?)) or (DATE(start_date) >= DATE(?) AND DATE(end_date) is null))', start_date, end_date, start_date)
```

same can be written as

```
lines.where('((DATE(start_date) >= DATE(:start_date) AND DATE(end_date) <= DATE(:end_date)) OR (DATE(start_date) <= DATE(:start_date) AND DATE(end_date) is null))', start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date)
```